# Symfony2 queries should be optimized for same entity fields

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have three entities: `Recipe`, `RecipeIngredient` and `Ingredient`. Each `Recipe` has many `RecipeIngredients`. Each `RecipeIngredient` has one `Ingredient`. My *RecipeAdmin* includes a Collection field for editing `RecipeIngredients`. The collection field contains many forms, each form for one `RecipeIngredient`. This form contains an entity field for selecting the `Ingredient`. The problem is that when I have 80 `RecipeIngredients` on the form, Symfony makes 80 same queries, one for each field.

These queries basically look like:

`SELECT (all the fields) FROM recipe_ingredients ORDER BY name`

The important thing is that all are the **same**. I don't think this is normal, how could I optimize so that only one query is required?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think u could try to use [ResultCache driver](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/doctrine.html).

```
doctrine:
  orm:
    ..
    ..
    result_cache_driver:
      type: memcache
      host: localhost
      port: 11211
      instance_class: Memcache
```

Comment: Does this require memcache to be installed?

Comment: Yes, but if u have no Memcached installed u can also use another ResultCache driver like one of "array", "apc" or "xcache".

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, the documentation says, that ResultCache by default uses array, so if it's true, I don't have to set anything. Is this correct?